# SQL Server 2012 Unable to Utilize Defined Amount of Locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, memory

So I've been beating my head against the wall for two days about this and I can't find a solution. I'm running a script to stage a large amount of data. This script requires roughly 35 million locks in order to complete; this translates into needing 3.36GB of memory available for locks. I set the number of locks to 37 million in the configured values, however after the reboot the running values are only allowing for 16,695,296 locks.

This corresponds to roughly 14% of available memory. As SQL Server 2012 can use 40% of available memory for locks, I should have plenty a room, but I don't. My question is: why can't SQL Server utilize the extra 26% of available lock memory? Everything I've read says that it should be able to.

Also, I did try running the locks on dynamic, but that also failed for the same reasons and with the same error codes: error 1204, instance can not obtain a lock resource. I know it's the server configuration and not the script, because I ran the exact same script, with the exact same data set on an older server (SQL Server 2008) without issue.

I appeal to the database admin gods for help; help me oh great ones!

Edit: This is a VM on a fail-over cluster, the VM has 16 GB of memory allotted to it. I've given SQL Server 12GB and left 4GB available for the host operating system.

Comment: What happens when you set the number of locks to 0 (meaning let sql server decide how much of them to use instead of you giving a hard value) ? [no of locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190253(v=sql.110).aspx) will be removed in future versions of SQL Server. Can you tell, whats the reason behind using `no of locks` as SQL Server is smart enough to allocate lock memory dynamically. If it was SybaseASE, you could have tune that.

Comment: Locks = 0 was how I had originally configured the SQL Server and in the locks = 0 configuration, it still gives the 1204 lock resource error. The reason why I manually defined the number of locks was based off a hunch that SQL Server was not dynamically allocating enough memory. Also, the first time I encountered this error, the server was set to lock = 0. My first thought was that it really did need more memory, so I added an extra 4GB of RAM, however I still got the 1204 error. This machine now has more RAM then my 2008 SQL Server, but my 08 SQL Server can run this job without the lock error

Comment: What is the exact version of your sql server on both server (working and nonworking) `select SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.]`. Also, have you compared the `sys.configurations` on both servers ? Especially Max Memory setting.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that this is a dedicated sql server box without having other apps like IIS running on it ? Run this query `SELECT request_session_id, COUNT (*) num_locks
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
GROUP BY request_session_id 
ORDER BY count (*) DESC` to find out what is using up all the locks.

Comment: @Kin This is a dedicated SQL box, there are no other apps running on it. The lock use is legitimate, it's the fact that SQL Server isn't able to use all of the memory available for locks that's the issue. It should be able to accommodate the 35 million locks without a problem, but it will only use 14% of the MaxMemory for locks as opposed to the 40% that it should. There are only 5 locks when I run the above query with the server in resting state.

Comment: @Kin The old server (the one that's working) is Enterprise 64bit SQL Server 2008 SP2 Build 10.50.4000.0, the new server (the one giving the error) is Enterprise 64bit SQL Server 2012 SP1 Build 11.0.3000.00. Both servers were originally running with identical configurations. MaxMemory is set to max (2147483647 MB aka all RAM not taken by the OS) on both machines. The actual amount of memory is 12GB of RAM on the old (working) server and 16GB on the new (not working) server. Originally both servers had 12GB, but I increased the amount on the new one by 4GB when I ran into the lock problem.

Comment: What about this process requires you to take so many fine grained locks? Why not TABLOCK and be done with it?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith : I suppose I could TABLOCK and call it good, but there are other processes that need to read the data from this DB while it's being updated. That's why I need to fine grained locks on the tables

Answer (score 1):

Is there any trace flag enabled or any tweaking into startup parameters of SQL server can you please check that.Have a look at below Microsoft support article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2199576/en-us
Keep max lock value to default

EXEC sp_configure 'locks', 0 ( I guess you tried this option already)

Now if you face this issue again best possible workaround will be to decrease the amount of rows being transferred. Every lock has memory associated with it so if there is lock contention I believe its somehow related to SQL Server buffer pool memory. Did you run DBCC MEMORYSTATUS and check value for

OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER (Total)       KB

please do tell us what is value of single page and multi page allocator for above clerk